# Определение наличие текста в переменной

Tags: javascript, smarty

Есть текст из базы выводиться в `{$goods.phone_2|escape}`

Задача: если есть наличие текста(кодировка разная), цифры, символ, то показываем строку

```
<p>Показывать строку</p>
<?
$str1 = "{$goods.phone_2|escape}";
?>
<?if (isset($str1)){?>    <p>Показывать строку</p>     <?}else{?><?}?>
```

Comment: @d_i_m99, Согласно правилам форума, вопросы не должны сводиться к решению либо завершению учебных заданий за учащихся. Пожалуйста, уточните, что вы сделали сами и что не получилось.

Comment: какая то ацкая смесь языков. smarty и js из того что мне удалось идентифицировать. Исправьте теги пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

strlen, isset...

**UPD**

Если не умеете читать, зачем минусовать?

```
$string = "я строка"; 
if (isset($string[1])) 
   echo "В строке есть > 2 символов";

if (strlen($string) > 2) 
   echo "В строке есть > 2 символов";
```

isset, кстате, работает быстрее чем strlen, но похоже вам еще не до этого.

В следующий раз учитесь корректно задавать вопрос, вы попросили php Я вам дал php, но и у вашего шаблонизатора есть функция strlen, т.е

```
{if $goods.phone_2|escape|strlen > 2}
    В строке есть > 2 символов
{/if}
```

Comment: <?$str1 = "{$goods.phone_1|escape}";?> 

  <?if (isset($str1)){?>    <span class="letter_teh">{$lang.phone_1}: <div class="letter_teh2">{$goods.phone_1|escape}</div></span>     <?}else{?><?}?>

Все равно Отображается если пустое и заполненное

Comment: Если не умеете читать, зачем минусовать?
$string = "я строка";
if (isset($string[1]))
   echo "В строке есть > 2 символов";

if (strlen($string) > 2)
   echo "В строке есть > 2 символов";

isset, кстате, работает быстрее чем strlen, но похоже вам еще не до этого.

Comment: У меня ещё нет право голосовать. Тем более бессмысленно за помощь минусовать!
Ваш вариант isset и strlen работает. 
С чтением и присвоением что-то не то $goods.phone_2 он её всегда видит с символом даже если пустая.

Comment: Я указал вам вариант работы с длинной строки функцией шаблонизатора, он в любом случае работать должен.

Answer (score 1):

Если я вас правильно понял, то как-то так:

```
if ($('.letter_teh2').html()) {
    $('.block2').show();
}
```